# IP Conflict on mac vm guest

Tags: networking, router, mac, virtual-machine

I have a host mac running Mac OS 14.4 (Sonoma). I am using VirtualBuddy to run the native VM capability, and a Guest instance of OS 14.0. I am having a IP conflict on ONE specific network... Starbucks. The host has no issues, and I can connect to my VPN with no issue. The IP address that the dialog says I am conflicting with is NOT the same IP as the host.

- I've tried with and without VPN, and even 3 different VPN clients
- Set to Bridge (ideal) or NAT, I get the same conflict.
- I have done DHCP Release/Renew about 100 times
- I have tried to manually set IP, and cycled through about 50+

  - Even on a day when I only see 3 other people in the shop, I get conflicts
- I've repeated the above Release/Renew and Manual, while also generating a new Mac Address each time
- I've removed the virtual device and recreated, three times
- I've tried bringing my travel router (gl.iNet Beryl), and using repeater, but the exact same issue
- I've restarted guest and host, multiple times
- I've even asked ChatGPT to try and troubleshoot

The network is using a Cisco Meraki router (since I can hit the gateway IP and see the status page). Not too much useful info I could get:

- Product model MR32
- "This access point is directly connected to a local network."
- "This access point is successfully connected to the Cisco Meraki cloud."
- "This access point is functioning normally"

Can't access the configure tab, and figure it'll certainly raise some alarms if I ask the barista to show me the router

How can I troubleshoot this? I've only had this issue on one other network, and I am a full time nomad, so I touch a lot of networks. I would have thought going NAT would solve this, but it is exactly the same behavior.